# How to create links to all subfolders containing specified text in their names

Tags: iphone, ios, bash, hyperlink

As specified in title I am looking for a way how to create links to all subfolders containing specified text in their names, so for example for all subfolders of root directory containing ".app" in their names an link will be created to "/AppLinks" directory. I would like to use it in bash script (open source, free).

Does anyone know how to do that?
I searched it by google with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find yourdir -type d -name '*.app' -exec ln -s {} /AppLinks \;
```

Find all directories named `something.app` in `yourdir`, and create a symlink to them in /AppLinks.

Answer (score 0):

single line bash-fu

```
function FUNCsymlink() { echo "$1"; fileName=`basename "$1"`; ln -s "$1" "/AppLinks/$fileName"; }; export -f FUNCsymlink; find `pwd`/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname "*.app" -exec bash -c "FUNCsymlink '{}'" \;
```

to easy reading:

```
function FUNCsymlink() { 
  echo "$1"; 
  fileName=`basename "$1"`; 
  ln -s "$1" "/AppLinks/$fileName"; 
}; 
export -f FUNCsymlink; 
find `pwd`/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname "*.app" -exec bash -c "FUNCsymlink '{}'" \;
```

you may have to adjust it a bit for your specific solution.

wherever you run it, it will create the symlinks to /AppLinks

it will only look for direct subfolders, not subfolders of subfolders, thats what I believe you need..